# Can't access server when with more than 2 GB of RAM available

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-forge

I made a server using forge, and me and my friends can play in the server without problems (i'm using Evolve, not Hamachi), but when I use a batch file to start the server and change -Xmx1024M to -Xmx2048M, the server runs without problems and I can access it, but my friends can't. I tried setting manually the ip for the server but it didnt work.

I'm using this batch script:

*"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx2048M -Xms512M -jar server.jar nogui
PAUSE*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it come up with any other messages?

Comment: If you run the command in a command prompt, does it give you other messages?

Comment: Nothing different

Comment: Pretty sure windows caps process memory at 2GB. At least the last time I knew of it did.

Comment: @Shelby115 I've ran a server at 4+GB, it reports using more than 2GB during heavy load. Perhaps you're thinking about a x86-32 system. In x86-64 the memory cap is much higher (not sure how high it is). The example given shows him using 64 bit java (unless he's using WinXP or earlier) so that shoudn't be the issue.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 x64, so you are right, it shouldn't be the problem. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx2048M -Xms512M -jar server.jar nogui PAUSE"
```

I believe both the Xmx and the Xms must be the same.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar server.jar nogui PAUSE"
```